# Relative layout - toRightOf and CenterInParent

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How it possible to have this way of layout:

Relative layout with 2 elements: icon on the left and text view, which is centered in parent.
Problem is when text became big it covers image, because its width is "wrap_content".

How to solve this?

http://prntscr.com/k8shpm
desired result

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the icon, you can always do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Loremem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum"/>
```

Comment: i know width, but doing this way adds margin to the right as well (because of centered horizontally)

Comment: now android:gravity="center" will center it 25dp to the right of real center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your explanation is that you need something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="the quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog" />
</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

If its not what you want, then please post your code to help understanding the problem

Comment: i want textview centered horizontally and in case of very big text - not cover icon

Comment: The above xml can also produce the same result.

Comment: Tested it - will center text not to real center of the screen, but to the (image.width / 2) to the right

Comment: Please upload a simple picture depicting your desired result.

Comment: I am not sure why the old answer didn't meet your need. Anyway I have updated the answer please check and tell if this works